# Swift: Cocoa, local notification not showing in mac OS Catalina

Tags: swift, cocoa, notifications

Hello notifications are not displayed on Mac OS Catalina, here is my code:

```
    func showNotification() {
        let notification = NSUserNotification()

        // All these values are optional
        notification.title = "Test of notification"
        notification.subtitle = "Subtitle of notifications"
        notification.informativeText = "Main informative text"
        notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName

        NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
    }
```

I noticed that in my mac application now when I open the application a notification request appears. Maybe I have to implement that? But I can not find any documentation on it. How to view local notification...

Even with UserNotification it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSUserNotification` has been deprecated past MacOS 10.14 as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsusernotification

Instead you might want to have a look at the `UserNotification` framework as in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications?language=objc

And in addition it is now crucial to request permission from users to authorize notifications.

Comment: Have you asked user for permission?

Comment: No I do not ask authorizations and that's the problem! Thank you. Before Catalina we were not obliged to ask

Comment: Do we have to ask each time?